# Regex to find unclosed HTML tags and close them

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need a regular expression , which gives me unclosed tags , and i can find them and close them programmatically.

Like , i have below text

```
<tag>
<p> hello world <p> this is <p>test.</p> this is test. <p> end it 
</tag>
```

i want to find unclosed tags from this and close them using Regex.

any idea??
Thanks Meghana

Comment: I personally think that a big problem will be the place WHERE the tag will be closed, 1) can be closed immediately after opening 2) can be closed when next tag is found (ANY) 3) Can be closed when the same type tag is found (Almost Useless?) And there are many more ways of closing tags, tags in tags etc.. It's really not that easy to find what you're looking for.

Comment: we can close before next tag starts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex is not a suitable tool for this task. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583) for a compelling demonstration of why.

I suggest you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) to parse and rewrite the HTML.

Comment: +1 for don't use regex to parse html - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: thanks @Oded for reply, but what if i treat this html as xml??

Comment: Agree with Oded here. The Agility Pack is forgiving in its parsing after which you can output the html well-formed. Be sure to test if nothing gets striped (thinking of comments, important white space). I'm sure the Agility pack will come close to a perfect output but be sure to investigate the options which you can call it with.

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can parse html with regexes

Comment: @meghana - If you have the kind of HTML you describe, the it is not valid XML and any XML parser will not be able to parse it

Comment: @Oded it will be text in one of xml tag

Comment: Take the advice from experts that know and understand why you shouldn't do what you are trying to do and run with it, simple as that.

Comment: @meghana - How _can it be_ valid XML content if it is missing close tags??? If it is in a `CDATA` section, that does not make it valid XML either.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be:

```
:%s/<p>[^<]\+<\/p>\zs\|\(<p>.\{-}[^<]\+\)/\1<\/p>/g
:%s/<\/p><\/p>/<\/p>/g
```

**Input:**

```
<tag>
<p> hello world <p> this is <p>test.</p> this is test. <p> end it·
</tag>
```

**Output:**

```
<tag>
<p> hello world </p><p> this is </p><p>test.</p> this is test. <p> end it·</p>
</tag>
```